# 눈 감 으면 코 베어가는 이곳 meaning?

Tags: translation

I'm tried to read a webtoon comic in Korean and I came across this sentence "눈 감 으면 코 베어가는 이곳" I want to know what it mean. Even better if you can break it down word by word?

Comment: Where did you see this sentence? What is the context? How much of Korean do you know?

Comment: http://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/%EB%88%88_%EA%B0%90%EC%9C%BC%EB%A9%B4_%EC%BD%94_%EB%B2%A0%EC%96%B4%EB%A8%B9%EC%9D%84_%EC%84%B8%EC%83%81

Comment: 저 표현은 가끔 쓰이는 표현인데요. "정신을 바짝 차려야 하는 장소" 정도로 해석할 수도 있습니다.

Answer (score 2):

Literally it means "(Here is) the place (where someone will) cut (your) nose if (you) close (your) eyes."

눈 감으면: if (you) close (your) eyes

코 베어가는: (someone will) cut (your) nose

이곳: (here is) the place (where)

So it will be a place with full of frauds, for example.

Comment: This is right. I think also, the closest phrase may be "dog-eat-dog (world)".  It describes a place where you had better not set down your purse and look away, cause someone's gonna take it.

Comment: FYI, the origin: **[Hanazuka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimizuka)**.